# Laravel - two columns with relationship to the same column in another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I set up a one-to-many Eloquent relationship between `User` and `Credit`

**User**

```
id | name
```

**Credit**

```
id | recipient | author | amount
```

where

`recipient` is `user.id`

`author` is `user.id`

In Laravel, the relationship for `recipient` is established:

```
class Credit extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient');
    }
}
```

But how do I add the relationship for `author` as well?

I tried:

```
class Credit extends Model {
    public function recipient() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient');
    }
    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author');
    }
}
```

i.e. I changed `user()` into two functions: `recipient()` and `author()`

But I am getting `Trying to get property of non-object`, which I think means that using `recipient()` or `author()`, Eloquent is unable to "bind" it to my `User` model.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a field called recipient and a relationship sharing the same name. Consider renaming one of them this is because laravel will use the field instead hence if you do

```
$credit->recipient->name
```

you can't access the user table since laravel will load the field. And the field does not have a property called name.

Earlier when the relationship was user() it worked. So consider finding a suitable name to user e.g credit_recipient()